# How to do a MYSQL Select dependant on a previous MYSQL Select

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that I need to SELECT fields from a MYSQL table depending on a previous MYSQL SELECT. Before I did this through an if and else if statement when it could only be one of two things but now I've added a third and so this no longer works. This is the effect I want:

```
$call = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE id = $_GET[id] LIMIT 1";

$latest = mysql_query($call);

$result = mysql_fetch_array($latest);

$post_cat = $result['category'];    

$sql="SELECT title, post_thumb, id FROM blog_posts WHERE category = $post_cat AND id <> $_GET[id] ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you see if you echo `$sql`?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. What do you mean by the $_GET works but $post_cat doesn't? Does that SQL statement work, but you want to amend it? Or is it the amended version, that doesn't work?

Comment: try putting category = '{$post_cat}' ....

Comment: @yevo: that's pointless. `{}` notation is only required if a var couldn't be disambiguated from text, e.g. `$foo = 'x'; echo "$foobar", "{$foo}bar"`. The quotes may be required, but OP hasn't said if that var is a string or a number.

Comment: agree main post was for the quote to be added I like using the brackets in sql makes it easier to read for me but I was mainly doing it to use quotes

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO How is it vulnerable to SQL Injection if I'm not taking any data into the database?

Comment: @andrewsi my question is how do I do a MYSQL Select dependant on a previous MYSQL Select

Comment: @Kflap - there's only one query in your question. Do you want to add some more code, so we can see where the variables are being set? What exactly is the problem with the SQL you've posted? Does it not work? If so, what isn't it doing that you expect it to do? Or is it the working version, and you want to add more to it? In which case, what do you want to add?

Comment: @andrewsi both queries are now in the question

Comment: @Kflap - thanks. But you've still not said what the problem is. Does that code work, or not?

Comment: @andrewsi ah don't worry about it imulsion solved it. Cheers for the help lads.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I'm new to PHP and MySQL so what alternative do I have?

Comment: @imulsion I'm just glad you managed to see what I was asking! Haha. It was not easy to explain.

Comment: [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @Kflap with mysql, it rarely is :)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Thanks :). Would not of known about this without you telling me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql="SELECT `title`, `post_thumb`, `id` FROM `blog_posts` WHERE category = '".$post_cat."' AND `id` = '".$_GET[id]."' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 6";
```

Put tables/columns in backticks and surround PHP variables in concatenated quotes. At the moment, your query asks MySQL to find a value in the category column which is `$post_cat`. Not the PHP variable `$post_cat`, the explicit string `$_post_cat`.

Comment: It's noted under the question, but it's worth pointing out this is vulnerable to SQL injection.